# iPhone: some UITableView's cells appears blank in edit

Tags: iphone, ios

I use tableView with custom cells and for cell drawing I use drawRect: method for scrolling performance. In edit mode when I move cells move and down sometimes some cells appear blank. And during scrolling also random cells start appear blank.Please look attached images. Can someone help to understand problem?

Comment: Here are corresponding screenshots http://www.screencast.com/users/Naira_as/folders/Default/media/c71df5b1-815c-4006-a891-eb7eac84a8eb http://www.screencast.com/users/Naira_as/folders/Default/media/b431628d-88b5-42df-8e24-dfa7c7f39420

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dequeueReusableCellForIdentifier then try removing that.
I mean to say alloc a new cell every time.

I am suggesting above based on assumption that your cell contains some heavy data which takes time in drawing. In this case if you reuse cell then it will take cell that goes out of visible screen and will paint draw new data in it.

If this doesn't help then please post some code showing how you are creating custom cell.

Comment: Yes, I use dequeueReusableCellForIdentifier, but without it I think performance will suffer. Any case I'll try  your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Performance will not suffer unless your table contains Too much data. All it will take is little bit more of memory....